# Website screen capture on Linux server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, node.js

I have a webpage written in AngularJS that needs to be turned into an image and sent as an email once a week to clients. The webpage is on S3 and my backend server is written partly in Rails and partly in Node. Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like PhantomJS (or based on Phantom CasperJS) - this is library like Selenium, headless browser. Possible to create screenshots with different device resolution and User-Agent. http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html